# Setting delgate amount

Tags: tezos-client, delegation, tzkt

I am using https://github.com/fireblocks/tezos_staking_sdk for staking. But it delegates or undelegates the whole amount. How can i mention the amount?How can I set staked amount while delegating tezos?

Answer (score 1):

In Tezos's "Liquid proof of stake" (LPOS) you can only ever delegate your entire balance to a baker. The funds are not locked, and can be moved, sold, transferred, deposited etc, at any time without having to take any action to undelegate before hand. Instead the network takes a snapshot every cycle of all the funds that were delegated and you simply get interest based off the amount that was in your wallet at the time of the snapshot

The only restriction is that a delegated wallet must retain a minimum balance of 0.000001 XTZ (the smallest amount possible). If you wanted to completely drain an account, you would need to undelegate first ... but this is actually more expensive than leaving the smallest amount

Answer (score 0):

Tezos delegation is often confusingly referred to as "staking". You don't delegate an amount, you delegate an account.

There is almost no reason to keep an account undelegated because, as @simon-mcloughlin says, the funds of a delegated account remain fully liquid.

Note that there have been discussions for a few months about actually adding staking for delegators (see https://research-development.nomadic-labs.com/adaptive-issuance.html#new-staking-mechanism) and in the context of this new feature, delegators would be able to stake an amount which would be locked.